# google sheets script Get row index of last entry in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to loop through values in a column. But the column is expanding and I don't want to change the range values every time I wish to add another entry to the column.

It is really frustrating that Google doesn't bother to add basic functionalities such as calling a row or a column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through every item in a column is actually very simple.

```
var column // int value of your column, 
           // assuming you know which column you want. 
           // (technically, your column number -1
var numRows = yourSheet.getLastRow();

for (var i; i < numRows; i++) {
  cell = table.getCell(i, column);

  // If you want to store all the cells text
  list.push(cell.getText());
}
```

Easy as that. If you want every cell of the table, just loop j inside i, and getCell(i, j);

Comment: This loops through a column. Which I can already perform. I am looking for a solution where the column keeps expanding to more rows and `table` can't be a hard-coded range unlike in your example.

Comment: I apologize, I what I should have said was, sheet.getLastRow(). This will get your last row with content, so it will be the size of your column at runtime.

Comment: Yea I just used that and it is working. You can make the change if you wish. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: If you downvoted, please leave a comment explaining why.